# How do I run a BeaufiulSoup4 command in BeauifulSoup 3?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add a new code to a larger project, but my code uses BeauifulSoup4 and the project originally used BeautifulSoup 3.2.1. If I try to run BeautifulSoup 3.2.1 on my code I get an error with the `.parent` commands that exist in my code. I try to upgrading the project to BeauifulSoup4, but I get errors from failed test in a part of the project that I prefer not to tamper with. My supervisor told me it's against company policy to have two different versions of the same pip installed. Is there a way for me to add the `.parent` command to BeautifulSoup 3.2.1?

`soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
na = soup.find(id='pizza stores')
links = na.parent.parent.find_all('a')`

when I try to run this code in BeautifulSoup 3 I get a

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

I changed changed
`BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')` to
`BeautifulSoup(response.content)` when trying to run in BeautifulSoup 3.

Comment: Which version in 3? I just checked on `3.2.1` and parent property does work fine

Comment: The project is also using `3.2.1` but .parent isn't working for me.

Comment: The problem is probably not in the parent property, but in the fact that you cannot find either na or its parent in the doc. Maybe try to reproduce with a very simple html.

Comment: Possible to include the response.content in question?

Comment: this code works perfectly if I run it in BeautifulSoup4 so I don't think that's the case, but how code for `.parent` may be structured between the 2 different versions of BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in `parent`, is in `find_all`, should be `findAll` in bs3.

```
doc = '<html><body><div><div id="pizza stores"></div></div><a>link</a></body></html>'
sp = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(doc)
na = sp.find(id='pizza stores')
na.parent.parent.findAll('a')

Out[44]: [<a>link</a>]
```